# How to reach the elements of an object array

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, object, arraylist

I have an object array in my app.

```
NSMutableArray *questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[questions addObject:[self addQuestion:@"QUESTION 1" option1:@"ans1" option2:@"ans2" option3:@"ans3" option4:@"ans4" option5:@"ans5" answer:2]];

[questions addObject:[self addQuestion:@"QUESTION 2" option1:@"ans1" option2:@"ans2" option3:@"ans3" option4:@"ans4" option5:@"ans5" answer:2]];
```

And in my wiew I have 6 different labels. One for the question and the others for the options. However I could not figure out how to reach for example to the "option 2" for the first object so that I can put its content to the label?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to be able to answer your question, you need to add some more information. Right now there isn't enough detail included for anyone to do much more than guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a NSDictionary (or NSMutableDictionary)! Or create a custom class! There are many great ways to accomplish this problem efficiently and safely, you will need to weigh your options. What you have now, will most certainly not work unless the return value for your method is indeed one object (like a NSMutableDictionary).

If you choose to use a dictionary, you might go about it like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *question = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:7];
[question setObject:@"Ask a question" forKey:@"question"];
[question setObject:@"Option 1" forKey:@"1"];
[question setObject:@"Option 2" forKey:@"2"];
[question setObject:@"Option 3" forKey:@"3"];
[question setObject:@"Option 4" forKey:@"4"];
[question setObject:@"Option 5" forKey:@"5"];
[question setObject:@"2" forKey:@"Answer"];

//Keep in mind, the numbers in these dictionary entries are treated as strings
```

You can then add this dictionary to the Array:

```
[questions addObject:question];
```

To access the correct answer for any given question dictionary object, you would call:

```
NSString *answer = [question objectForKey:[question objectForKey:@"Answer"]];
```

..which would return a string: "Option 2."

To access the text of an option to put in a label:

```
NSString *option = [question objectForKey:@"2"];
```

..which would also return a string: "Option 2."

Hope this helps, happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

```
someLabel2.text = [questions objectAtIndex:2];
```

If this does not answer your quesiton (which I somehow guess:) then please add some more relevant information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the first object in the array

id question = [questions objectAtIndex: 0];

// TODO: use whatever accessor you have to get properties
// NSString *message = ...

// set label text
label.text = message;
```

For more help please clarify your question a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

well that all depends souly on how the `addQuestion:option1:option2:option3:option4:option5:` method works. I'd imagine that you have some sort of accessor methods to access all of those options in the object that is returned by that method. It would help if you could post more of your code. Also, it would be better to have the questions array be an instance variable, so that you can access it from other methods of that class, and possibly from outside the class depending on how you set up the accessor methods.

I would imagine that your code would work something like this (again, I don't know because you haven't posted your full source).

```
// this would be an instance of your class
id someObject = [questions objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *option1 = someObject.option1;
NSString *option2 = someObject.option2;
NSString *option3 = someObject.option3;
NSString *option4 = someObject.option4;
NSString *option5 = someObject.option5;
```